# É possível ler um arquivo do Quick Report (qrp) pelo PHP?

Tags: php, quickreport

Olá, tenho um arquivo do Quick Report (formato .qrp). Preciso analisar os dados dele de dentro do PHP, mas não obtive sucesso.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: É possível disponibilizar o arquivo, ou parte dele?

Comment: A única forma que vejo para você utilizar esse relatório em QuickReport, seria executando (via aplicação Delphi ou outra que suporte) e exportando para HTML, dai sua aplicação PHP poderia fazer a leitura e analise dos dados.

Comment: Tem como eu fazer essa conversão no delphi através do PHP? tipo chamar um exe com parâmetros, sei lá... é porque o processo será automatizado.

Comment: Thiago, eu poderia através de um email

Comment: @WallaceMagalhães achei muito interessante tua dúvida e gostaria de analisar melhor, poderia enviar ao meu e-mail? thgsantos16@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tecnicamente a resposta é: Pode sim.

1. Baixe esse aplicativo: **SmartQRP** http://download.cnet.com/SmartQRP/3000-10743_4-10433393.html (apenas 686 Kbytes)

Ele pode ser operado por linha de comando e exportar para PDF, deverá utilizá-lo com a função [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php).

Depois precisará disso:

2. **PDFParser**:

   - Instalação: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser
   - Documentação: http://www.pdfparser.org/documentation

Comentário na documentação:

> PdfParser, a standalone PHP library, provides various tools to extract data from a PDF file.
>   Currently, secured documents are not supported

Infelizmente eu não tenho nenhum arquivo QRP para testar.

Comment: Olá! Acredito que sua resposta esteja muito próxima da solução. Sei como utilizar shell_exec, mas, como utilizo o SmartQRP via linha de comando? No caso, executar a função dele de converter pra PDF? Obrigado desde já!

Comment: tem que baixar o SmartQRP e instalar, e testar com algum arquivo QRP. Deve ser algo do tipo: " Smartqrp.exe Relatorio.qrp /pdf ".

Comment: Não está funcionando, qualquer comando que eu tento ele abre o programa :c

Comment: se você tiver tempo, pode tentar utilizar essa [VCL](https://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=248&t=Export_From_Quickreport_To_PDF_And_Other_Formats) que exporta QRP para PDF, fazer um programinha em Delphi, aceitando parâmetro pela linha de comando, e exportando direto em outro arquivo no formato PDF.

Comment: Obrigado! Você me colocou no caminho certo para que eu pudesse resolver o problema. Fiz o que sugeriu, e, finalmente, consegui fazer a conversão.